# How to turn an html string from an array into html using angularjs ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following array where each item's value is a string that is html. How can I turn this string into executable html, so that it can be shown?

```
[
{html:'<button>name</button>'},
{html:'<table > <thead> <tr> <th>#</th> <th>UserName</th> <th>Time</th> <th>Comments</th> <th>Reply</th> <!-- <th>like or dislike</th> --> </tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr> <td>1,001</td> <td><a href="#" >Lorem</a></td> <td>2014-10-31</td> <td>ipsum</td> <td> <button type="submit" > <span ></span></button></td> </tr> <tr> <td>1,002</td> <td>amet</td> <td><a><span ></span></a></td> <td><a><span ></span></a></td> <td> <button type="submit" > <span ></span></button></td> </tr> <tr> <td>1,003</td> <td>Integer</td> <td>nec</td> <td>odio</td> <td> <button type="submit"> <span></span></button></td> </tr> <tr> <td>1,003</td> <td>libero</td> <td>Sed</td> <td>cursus</td> <td> <button type="submit" > <span></span></button></td> </tr> </tbody> </table>'},
{html:'<p>myhtml</p>'}
]
```

See codepen here: http://codepen.io/chriscruz/pen/YPwVmb

See below for HTML

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
        <thead>
            <th>Email</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="(id,item) in data">
                <td>{{item.html}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


</body>
```

Javascript and Angular JS

```
    var app = angular.module("app", ["firebase"]);

    app.factory("TestArray", ["$firebase", function($firebase) {
        lst = [
        {html:'<button>name</button>'},
        {html:'<table > <thead> <tr> <th>#</th> <th>UserName</th> <th>Time</th> <th>Comments</th> <th>Reply</th> <!-- <th>like or dislike</th> --> </tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr> <td>1,001</td> <td><a href="#" >Lorem</a></td> <td>2014-10-31</td> <td>ipsum</td> <td> <button type="submit" > <span ></span></button></td> </tr> <tr> <td>1,002</td> <td>amet</td> <td><a><span ></span></a></td> <td><a><span ></span></a></td> <td> <button type="submit" > <span ></span></button></td> </tr> <tr> <td>1,003</td> <td>Integer</td> <td>nec</td> <td>odio</td> <td> <button type="submit"> <span></span></button></td> </tr> <tr> <td>1,003</td> <td>libero</td> <td>Sed</td> <td>cursus</td> <td> <button type="submit" > <span></span></button></td> </tr> </tbody> </table>'},
        {html:'<p>myhtml</p>'}
        ]
        return lst;
    }]);

    app.controller("ctrl", ["$scope","TestArray", function($scope,TestArray) {
        $scope.data = TestArray;
        //$scope.data = Emails;

    }]);
```

This is the desired result that I'd like to see: http://codepen.io/chriscruz/pen/pvgwzw?editors=101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [Updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYQyzv)

you need to add `angular-sanitize.js` file

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

and import `ngSanitize` module in `app`

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["firebase",'ngSanitize']);
```

then you can bind the html using `ng-bind-html` directive

```
<td ng-bind-html="item.html"></td>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with some html code. Take for example: http://codepen.io/chriscruz/pen/KwVqKq?editors=101. I'm able to manipulate the string in the array formation process if need be - is there anything I could do to make this work?

Comment: please check your html is not a messy one. seems like your html is not well structured.

Comment: Thanks - I had some cleaning up to do. I used python's Beautifulsoup to clean up the html in the array and replaced all quotations with an apostrophe. This seems to do the trick.